# ReaderWriter Synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading

This code uses a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to store data (on a disk or wherever), so that only one thread can write and many threads can read.

All writers should be finished before reading, and the write should not block the caller.

Basically my solution would work, but it doesn't look and feel natural to .NET since 4.0 the *Task Parallel Library* (TPL) was introduced...

```
class JsonApplicationContainerDAO : IApplicationContainerDAO
{

    private static volatile IApplicationContainerDAO instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private readonly BlockingCollection<ICollection<IApplicationConfiguration>> itemsToSave = new BlockingCollection<ICollection<IApplicationConfiguration>>();
    private readonly Thread writerThread ;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();


    public static IApplicationContainerDAO Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new JsonApplicationContainerDAO();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    private JsonApplicationContainerDAO()
    {
        writerThread =  new Thread(WriteItems);
        writerThread.Start();
    }


    private void WriteItems(object obj)
    {
        ICollection<IApplicationConfiguration> item = null;
        while((item = itemsToSave.Take()) != null){
            try
            {
                readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
                //do stream stuff here
            }
            finally
            {
                readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock(); 
            }
        }
    }


    public ICollection<IApplicationConfiguration> LoadAll()
    {
        try
        {
            readerWriterLock.EnterReadLock();
            //do stream stuff here
        }
        finally
        {
            readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Persist(ICollection<IApplicationConfiguration> items)
    {
        itemsToSave.Add(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: and the question is? BTW: you start the writer thread in constructor but when does that thread end and when does `Take` return null? You seem to always "append" to the persistence layer (file) - do you ever need to remove items?  Can multiple threads concurrently call `Persist`/why use `BlockingCollection`?

Comment: The question is, is there a better way with usage of the Task Parrallel Library

Blocking queue is used i want to have the write in some kind transactional, so like a Queue i will write every object in the order it has been added to the collection...

i abstracted the logic of the write here because it has nothing to do with the problem/question..

The in this sample the thread will never return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For this:

   > ```
   > try
   > {
   >     readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
   >     //do stream stuff here
   > }
   > finally
   > {
   >     readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock(); 
   > }
   > ```

   `EnterWriteLock` should be before the `try` statement.

   > Suppose the `EnterWriteLock()` fails. For whatever reason.
   >   Then the one thing you shouldn't do is to Exit a lock you never Entered.

   Source: [C# - Lock question using EnterWriteLock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7071103/843804)
2. Please note that singleton nowadays is rather an antipattern. They make testing harder and often hide dependencies which leads to spaghetti code which is really hard to work with. [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/843804)